# RoR Path Helper link is backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sentence model and set up in the routes.rb

```
map.resrouces :sentence
```

However, when I use edit_sentence_path(sentence) it sets up the url to be

```
/sentence/1/edit
```

instead of

```
/sentence/edit/1
```

Am I missing something? I am not exactly sure if I am doing this correctly since I am trying to do the data access stuff without using scffold, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct URL when you use `map.resources` rather than the `:controller/:action/:id` convention when `map.resources` is not used. So, you're doing it exactly right.